# How to display date format in Angular 8 Excel Reader?

Tags: excel, angular

I followed a tutorial for a project on Angular 8.
I used xlsx and tried to read an excel file and to display the table.

Here below the code I followed from the tutorial:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import  * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Component({   selector: 'app-excelsheet',   templateUrl: './excelsheet.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./excelsheet.component.css'] }) export class ExcelsheetComponent implements OnInit {

  data: [][];   constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {   }

  onFileChange(evt: any) {
    const target : DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);

    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');

    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;

      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary' });

      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];

      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      console.log(ws);

      this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 1}));

      console.log(this.data);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);   }

}
```

The problem is that for the 3rd row where I am supposed to get a date, I get an integer

[image: data as sorted (3rd row is supposed to be a date)]

My html file is:

```
<p>excelsheet works!</p>

<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false" />

<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
        {{cell}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I was opting to use a pipe on the html but not sure if that's the best way as I would need to change the *ngFor td directive.

Is there a better way?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Convert the number from Excel to js date using this formula :

```
d = new Date((numberFromExcel-25569)*86400000)
```

Explication :

- **numberFromExcel** : number of days from 01/01/1900 to the date.
- **25569** : number of days from 01/01/1900 to 01/01/1970.
- **86400000** : number of milliseconds in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Add `cellDates: true`  on the line  `const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true });`

Comment: It worked for me in my code but dates are appearing like `Tue Apr 07 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` Please guide me how can I change format to dd-mm-yyyy. Thanks in advance @lorenzo

Comment: in the cell of row of data add `new Date(cell).toISOString()` on html add pipe `| date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'`